# Linear dependence vectors proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Let vectors $v_1,v_2,\dots, v_n$ be linearly independent.

Let $v$ be a vector s.t. $v,v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n$ are linearly dependent. How do I prove that $v$ is a linear combination of $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n$?

Comment: What is the definition of "linear independence" you are using? What have you tried?

Comment: Write down what it means for $v,v_1,...v_n$ to be linearly dependent. Then use the other condition to show that the multiplier for $v$ is non-zero. Divide across by this constant.

Comment: To me it means is v1,v2 ... vn are linearly independent then      a1v1 + a2v2...... + anvn = 0 has only trivial solution i.e. a1=a2 =.... an = 0

Comment: There is a definition of linear independence: $v_k$ are linearly independet **iff** $\sum_k \alpha_k v_k = 0$ implies $\alpha_k = 0$.

Comment: Logically the answer is obvious but how can it be proven mathematically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $v,v_1,\ldots ,v_n$ are linearly dependent over $k$ then $rv+r_1v_1+\cdots +r_nv_n=0$ with some $r,r_i\in k$ not all zero. Suppose that $r=0$. Then all $r_i=0$ because $v_1,\ldots ,v_n$ are linearly independent over $k$. This is a contradiction, because not all $r_i$ and $r$ are zero. Hence $r\neq 0$ and we have
$$
v=-r^{-1}(r_1v_1+\cdots +r_nv_n).
$$